# How can I suppress the output image generation in detectObjectsFromImage()?

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am using ImageAI's detectObjectsFromImage function to run a pre-trained keras model on certain images. It works fine but it generates an output image with enclosed boxes against objects. Ideally, I dont want the output image to be generated as I just need to detect in code and perform action on it. I tried not to give output argument but it still created a jpg file.

Any ideas how to suppress the output image?

code:

```
detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join("pics",filename))
for eachObject in detections:
    if(eachObject["name"]=="person"):
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `output_type` to `"array"`:

```
detected_image_array, detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(output_type="array", input_image="image.jpg" ) # For numpy array output type
```

Described in the docs: https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/blob/master/imageai/Detection/README.md

Note: You can also set the `input_type` to `"array"`.